# Find similar records in a table using LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to find people with same name and surname in one table and so far I have written this LINQ query. This query gives me a cross join result. Can someone help me to remove the similar set of results, please?
I want to show the matching records in a grid and user can open details of each one of them to see if they are actually duplicates or not and then take action on it

For eg
consider a person's id as number
the current result is 
(1,2)
(1,3)
(2,1)
(2,3)
(3,1)
(3,2)
I want the result to be (1,2)
(1,3)
(2,3)

```
var query = from ori in db.People
            from dup in db.People                        
            select new DuplicateDataSet
               {
                 ActiveMember = ori,
                 DuplicateMember = dup
               };

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(memberFirstName))
     query = query.Where(w => w.ActiveMember.GivenName.Trim() == memberFirstName && w.DuplicateMember.GivenName.Trim() == memberFirstName );
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(memberSurname))
     query = query.Where(w => w.ActiveMember.Surname.Trim() == memberSurname && w.DuplicateMember.Surname.Trim() == memberSurname);

query = query.Where(w => w.ActiveMember.PersonID != w.DuplicateMember.PersonID && w.ActiveMember.MemberID != w.DuplicateMember.MemberID);
newList = query.Take(100).ToList();
```

Comment: What those numbers mean? And why expected result still contains duplicates `1,2 1,3 2,3`?

Comment: Those number can be considered as person's id. I want to show them all in a grid and user can open details of each one of them to see if they are actually duplicates or not and then take action on it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you should search for people with same names:

```
 from p in db.People
 group p by new { GivenName = p.GivenName.Trim(), Surname = p.Surname.Trim() } into g
 where g.Count() > 1 // this condition filters out people without duplicates
 select new {
    Name = g.Key,
    Duplicates = g.ToList()  // here you will get people with same name
 }
```

You can use `Duplicates = g.Select(p => p.PersonID).ToList()` if you want to get just ids of duplicated people. There will not be any repetitions in ids. E.g. if people 1, 2, and 3 have same name *John Doe*, then you will get

```
 { 
    Name: { GivenName: "John", Surname: "Doe" },
    Duplicates: [1, 2, 3]
 }
```

You can do any permutations with these ids if you need to. E.g. you can use two loops:

```
private static IEnumerable<Tuple<T,T>> GetPermutations<T>(params T[] values)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < values.Length; j++)
            yield return Tuple.Create(values[i], values[j]);
    }
}
```

Test

```
GetPermutations(1, 2, 3) // returns (1,2) (1,3) (2,3)
```

Note: instead of trimming names each time you read them from database, consider to put trimmed values to database.

Comment: Thanks I will try it